# link_to params Get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to create link  like this

```
= link_to vacancy.new_candidates_count, hiring_candidates_path(???)
```

where ??? some params.

How I can redirect to hiring_candidates_path with params like this

```
 Parameters: {"grid_filter"=>{"vacancies"=>["1"]}
```

On page  hiring_candidates I can use filters and I can see in terminal all params which I send:

```
Started GET "/hiring/candidates.json?grid_filter%5Bgroup%5D=&grid__search=false&grid_nd=1396122997602&grid_rows=30&grid_page=1&grid_sidx=id&grid_sord=desc&grid_filter%5Bvacancies%5D%5B%5D=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-29 21:56:37 +0200
Processing by Hiring::CandidatesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"grid_filter"=>{"group"=>"", "vacancies"=>["1"]}, "grid__search"=>"false", "grid_nd"=>"1396122997602", "grid_rows"=>"30", "grid_page"=>"1", "grid_sidx"=>"id", "grid_sord"=>"desc"}
```

Waiting for your help)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass them as `query params`:

```
= link_to vacancy.new_candidates_count, hiring_candidates_path("grid_filter"=>{"vacancies"=>["1"]})
```

Upon clicking, this link will create a url with query params like

`/hiring/candidates.json?grid_filter%5Bvacancies%5D%5B%5D=1`

Answer (score 0):

Further to Kirti's post, you *may* wish to define the params in your routes (something called [bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters)):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :hiring do
   collection do
       get "candidates(/:vacancies)", action: :candidates
   end
end
```

This would allow you to load a url with "naked" data (such as `/candidates/1`). Obviously this won't fit into your question directly, but it will certainly help in the future

---

You may also want to look at [JSON query constructs](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#json-explained) to appreciate how JSON paths work:

```
url/?param1=xxx&param2=xxx
```